# How to run a macro in a buffer that would take an argument?

Tags: keyboard-macros

If I want, for example, add all numbers in a  line with a keyboard macro, how can I do it?

It would add:
1 1 34 53
into: 89.

Or, given a word:
asdf
transform it into 
fdsa

I know how to define the macro, bind it, and name it.

I have no interest in inputting the numbers in a table. This is meant for easy of use, like typing amount, interest, years, and getting a total amount.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best not to try doing this with a keyboard macro. However, a simple elisp function to do it is easy to write:

```
(defun db48x/add-up-numbers (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((sum (apply #'+
                    (mapcar #'string-to-number
                            (split-string (buffer-substring beg end))))))
    (delete-region beg end)
    (insert (number-to-string sum))))
```

It operates on the region, so select the text containing the numbers first. You can bind it to the key of your choice or call it directly (`M-x db48x/add-up-numbers`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `C-x Q` during macro definition? It's for putting in minibuffer prompts for getting variable arguments into the macro at runtime.

As for adding a row of numbers in a region, you may find `M-x Quick-Calc` more convenient.

The last option of course is to edit the macro and insert something like this:

```
(prompt (if arg (read-from-minibuffer "PROMPT: ") "Input: "))
```